# How to prove normal cones are closed?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $C$ be a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and let $\bar{x} \in C$. Then the *normal cone* $N_{C}(\bar{x})$ is closed and convex.  Here, we're defining the normal cone as follows:

$$N_{C}(\bar{x}) = \{v \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \vert \langle v, x - \bar{x} \rangle \le 0, \forall x \in C \}.$$

Proving convexity is straightforward, as is proving $N_{C}(\bar{x})$ is closed when $C$ is open ($i.e.$ every $x \in C$ is an interior point).  However, I'm not sure how to prove that $N_{C}(\bar{x})$ is closed more generally?

Comment: I have one small question. May you explain why is C a convex set? I mean if C is not convex, how would the definition of normal cone be affected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write $N_C(\bar{x}) = \cap_{x \in C} \{v | \langle v, x-\bar{x} \rangle \le 0 \}$.

Hence $N_C(\bar{x})$ is the intersection of closed hyperplanes which is closed (the
function $v \mapsto \langle v, x-\bar{x} \rangle$ is continuous).

This approach also shows that $N_C(\bar{x})$ is convex.

Comment: ....and now I see why this proof has been omitted from so many books that I've looked through. Thanks @copper.hat.

Comment: @StevenA: There are many cute tricks, after a while you will add them to your quiver :-).

Comment: @copper.hat Have a quesiton.Why you changed the definition of $N_C$?I have difficulty for understanding it

Comment: @program_craft The expressions are equivalent, it is fairly straightforward to show. The expression above shows that $N_C$ is the intersections of closed convex sets.